# mod_proxy: redirect to dynamic port

Tags: apache2, mod-proxy

I running apache2 as proxy for other apache2 servers, which listen on ports made randomly.
So I need to redirect correctly. I made next 2 redirect models.

```
ProxyPassMatch ^(/.*)$ http://`127.0.0.1`127.0.0.1:$1
#it always give syntax error
```

and

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule /(.*) https://`127.0.0.1`:$1 [R] 
#this nothing do
```

Has anyone any idea, how can I redirect to port correctly? or correct Syntax for first method.

Thank you.

Comment: "which listen on ports made randomly". (a) why? and (b) how? and how do you expect to be able to encode a random port into a fixed configuration file?

Comment: HOW? Its easy. when some action initiated, on another server(its virtual server on VirtualBox) I start httpd listening on X port, or X+1, X+2,... and i need to use httpd(on base server) to serve as proxy, and redirect exactly same requests, change port only.

WHY? it's top secret :D

Comment: So, again, how do you plan to encode a dynamic port number into a static configuration file? Stressing about the syntax of a rewrite rule is futile until you solve that problem.

Comment: So, again, how do you plan to encode a dynamic port number into a static configuration file? 
good question. That's why I open this post.

Comment: But *what's the question?* Even if you could get the dynamic port number into the static configuration file, you would then have to restart the server to get it to read that file. Surely it's obvious that the dynamic port is part of the problem, not part of the solution?